# Js, PHP WITH AJAX: how to determine the letter grade of students using javascript with ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

So I made a program about an exam and I need to determine the letter grades of students but first, they have to answers some questions then base on what score the student gets the student will get a letter grade, someone recommended me to use AJAX because I need to do the process itself in the form without refreshing so I tried to make it but I ended up getting confused can someone help me, please.

I’m confused because everytime I got the score the letter grades are not appearing

Here are the codes:

```html
        <div class = "form">
    <button id = "submit" name = "submit"  value = "submit" > SUBMIT </button>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <h3> Are you sure you want to submit? </h3>
        <button id = "yes" name = "yes" class = "yes" value = "submit" onclick ="loadDoc()"> YES </button>
        <button id = "no" name = "no" class = "no"> NO </button>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div id="myModalLast" class="modalLast">
      <div class="modal-contentLast">
       <a href = "personal.php"> <span class="close">&times;</span> </a>

    <div class = "pic">
        <img src="Logo.png" width = "150" height = "150">
    </div>  
        <h3> Full name: Cathleen Joyce Imperial Almeda </h3>  
        <h3> Total items:20 <p id = "score" name = "scorename"></p> </h3>  
       <h1> <br><p id = "scores" name = "realscores"></p>

       Rank:<p id = "rank"></p>
    </h1> 

      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

This is for the ajax part:

```html
        <script>
    function loadDoc() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("score").innerHTML =
          this.responseText;
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("post", "examExtension.php", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
```

And this for `examExtension.php`:

```php
        <?php


    $score = isset($_POST['score']) ? $_POST['score'] : '';


    if ($score > 19 and $score < 21){
    echo "A+";
    }
    if($score  > 18 and $score< 20){
    echo "A";
    }
    if($score  > 17 and $score< 19){
    echo "A-";
    }
    if($score  > 16 and $score< 18){
    echo "B+";
    }
    if($score  > 15 and $score < 17){
    echo "B";
    }
    if($score  > 14 and $score< 16){
    echo "B-";
    }
    if($score  > 13 and $score< 15){
    echo "C+";
    }
    if($score  > 12 and $score < 14){
    echo "C";
    }
    if($score  > 11 and $score< 13){
    echo "C-";
    }
    if($score  > 10 and $score< 12){
    echo "D+";
    }
    if($score  > 9 and $score< 11){
    echo "D";
    }

    ?>
```

And lastly, this is for the counting of scores it is based on how many radio buttons the student correctly clicked.

```html
         <script>document.getElementById("yes").addEventListener("click", function() {
      let numberOfCorrectAnswers = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio].correct:checked").length;
      document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Your Score: " + numberOfCorrectAnswers;


    });


    </script>
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Did your someone mean "getting the scores with AJAX" or "submitting the answers with AJAX". The latter would make more sense. Except if you want to get the score from any page, then the former is the one to go with.

Comment: i got the score but when i try to fetch it to determine the letter grade, it doesn't work , blank will only appear

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a blank value because you are not sending anything to your PHP script. Your `examExtension.php` script expects a value called `score`. Without that value all the `if` statements are coming up false and thus nothing is ever returned to your request.

You can pass a value into the `xhttp.send()` function to send the score to your PHP file so it can read it and calculate a result for you.

### Edit

I've used the [`Fetch API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) instead of your [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) implementation. It's the same, as in it they both make AJAX requests, but more modern.

```
const scoreElement = document.getElementById("score");
const yesButton = document.getElementById("yes");

yesButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let numberOfCorrectAnswers = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio].correct:checked").length;

  console.log('Calculating grade');

  // Pass amount of correct answers to the loadDoc function.
  loadDoc(numberOfCorrectAnswers).then((grade) => {
    scoreElement.innerHTML = `Your Score: ${grade}`;
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log('Calculating failed', error);
  });

});

// Use the 'numberOfCorrectAnswers' value as the 'score' variable in this function.
const loadDoc = (score) => fetch("examExtension.php", {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({ score })
}).then((response) => {
  if (response.status !== 200 && !response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`loadDoc has failed. status: ${response.status}`;
  }
  console.log(Calculation complete);
  return response.text();
});
```

```php
<?php

// Check if the score is given. If it is, continue. Otherwise stop the script.
if (!isset($_POST['score']) {
  echo 'No score has been given';
  exit;
}

// Convert score value to a number.
$score = intval($_POST['score']);

if ($score > 19 and $score < 21) {
  echo "A+";
} else if ($score > 18 and $score < 20) {
  echo "A";
} else if($score > 17 and $score < 19) {
  echo "A-";
} else if ($score > 16 and $score < 18) {
  echo "B+";
} else if ($score > 15 and $score < 17) {
  echo "B";
} else if ($score > 14 and $score < 16) {
  echo "B-";
} else if ($score > 13 and $score < 15) {
  echo "C+";
} else if ($score > 12 and $score < 14) {
  echo "C";
} else if ($score > 11 and $score < 13) {
  echo "C-";
} else if ($score > 10 and $score < 12) {
  echo "D+";
} else if($score  > 9 and $score < 11) {
  echo "D";
}

exit;

?>
```

Comment: no score has been given is the result but when i tried to do it console the score is there and it is 14

Comment: Is your AJAX request being send? Is the console giving any errors when you try to send it?

Comment: i got no errors i look at in the network, yes the request is sending, am i correct do i look for it there?

Comment: Try to also remove the `onclick ="loadDoc()"` from your "yes" button. It might mess things up. Can you check if the PHP script receives the `score` variable by just echo-ing `echo $_POST['score'];` or `return $_POST['score']` at the start of your PHP script. I'll do a rewrite of your `XMLHttpRequest` and use the `Fetch API` instead, which is newer and, in my opinion, easier to use.

Comment: I deleted it as you said and also i tried echo and return, for the echo it has "no score has been given", for result it just doesn't have any result. thank you for helping me

Comment: I've updated the JS part which sends the value to the server in JSON format. Try it again and see if the server returns a value.